# get Latitude with decimal sign

Tags: java, android

I want to get longitude and latitude I use this method and it's work fine but when I change my phone language to Persian it does not work.

```
lattude = location.convert(location.getLatitude(), location.FORMAT_SECONDS);
lattude = replaceDelimiters(lattude, decimalPlace);
char lonCardinal = location.getLatitude() >= 0 ? 'N' : 'S';
lattude = lattude + " " + lonCardinal;
txt5.setText(lattude);
```

decimal method:

```
@NonNull
private String replaceDelimiters( String str, int decimalPlace) {
    str = str.replaceFirst(":", "°");
    str = str.replaceFirst(":", "'");
    int pointIndex = str.indexOf(".");
    int endIndex = pointIndex  + 1 + decimalPlace;
    if (endIndex < str.length()) {
        str = str.substring(0, endIndex);
    }
    str = str + "\"";

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "it's not work" means.

Comment: when my phone language is English show  longitude and latitude  but when i change it the phone language to Persian  not showing longitude and latitude

Comment: Use your debugger to step through your code, while the device is in Persian, and determine what is and is not running of your code.